# Create directory without Read-Only attribute on windows in Java

Tags: java, windows, directory, nio, file-permissions

I've been struggling for awhile figuring out how to create directory without the read-only attribute on Windows using :

```
Files.createDirectory(path, attrs);
```

The *`attrs`* attribute is unclear for me, the only example I could find were the one using the POSIX standard :

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxr-x---");
FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms);
Files.createDirectory(file, attr);
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to create the *`FileAttribute`* for a Windows system in order to unset the *`ReadOnly`* attribute.

For now I'll just create the directory without paying attention to the *`attrs`* parameter and edit the attribute after creating the directory.

Thanks

Comment: If your file system supports/uses ACL then take a look at [`AclFileAttributeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html) and related classes. I don't know much about it, but maybe you'll find what you're looking for. At the bottom of the class javadoc it talks about using `AclEntry` objects in a `FileAttribute`.

Comment: FYI, setting the readonly attribute on a directory only prevents an empty directory from being deleted, not the contents of the directory. So it doesn't actually make a "readonly" directory. This is in contrast to the immutable file attribute/flag that's supported by some Unix systems such as Linux and BSD, which does act on the contents of a directory.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>So, to the best of my knowledge this is a windows problem not a Java one. It might be while you're struggling to find an answer. 
On creation files in windows follow the OS's default permission set, **laughs in linux**. If you'd like to create it with different permissions set your OS default permissions first and they should apply to your file.</strike>

I wish I knew of a neater way to do it. Unfortunately I do not, sorry. 
[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549)

EDIT: Hey, you learn something new everyday, Oracle added a setWritable. This may solve your problem!

```
File file = new File("DemoFile");
if(file.setWritable(false)) {
System.out.println("Successful");
}
else {
System.out.println("Well thats unfortunate, guess I was wrong");
}

if(file.setWritable(true)) {
System.out.println("Re-enabled writing");
}
else {
System.out.println("Failed to re-enable writing on file.");
}
```

Have a great day!

Comment: Well, actually my question was not about how to unset the parameter but more about how to use `FileAttribute` parameter in `Files.createDirectory(path, attrs);` method in a Windows system, thanks for the answer though !